# How to Connect MongoDB with IBM Cloud Function using NodeJS and get the data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, ibm-cloud-functions

I need to know how I can connect IBM Cloud Function with data base MongoDB and getting the data to show it, I try with the https://cloud.ibm.com/functions/ and I use the hello world function, I change in the code but is not working

Comment: The code for an IBM Cloud solution tutorial on a database-driven Slackbot uses Cloud Function access Db2 or PostgreSQL. See here https://github.com/IBM-Cloud/slack-chatbot-database-watson/ and adapt it to MongoDB

Comment: Can you paste up the sample code that isn't working for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a good documentation of how mongoDB can be used with IBM Cloud functions: https://thecodebarbarian.com/getting-started-with-ibm-cloud-functions-and-mongodb

It has a step by step flow for getting through your requirement for NodeJS.

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb');

const uri = 'mongodb+srv://OMITTED.mongodb.net/test';

let client = null;

async function main(params) {
   const reused = client != null;
   if (client == null) {
     client = await mongodb.MongoClient.connect(uri);  
   }

   const docs = await client.db('test').collection('tests').find().toArray();

   return { body: { result: docs, reused } };
 }

 exports.main = main;
```

The code above should be what you end up with.